# 'JNI FatalError called: Unable to load library:-mjBRuiRk8odgUr7LcW7eNw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so [dlopen failed: library "libil2cpp.so" not found]'

Tags: unity-game-engine

'JNI FatalError called: Unable to load library: /data/app/~~rn1IlinzUZic7esEjB56lg==/com.pack.myapp-mjBRuiRk8odgUr7LcW7eNw==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so [dlopen failed: library "libil2cpp.so" not found]'

Here is my Local.properties FIles

sdk.dir=/Users/root/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/root/Desktop/flutter
ndk.dir=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.18f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=8.0.0`enter code here`
flutter.versionCode=50

I am stuck in this in 4 days but nothing works.
I am implementing in flutter android build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to build

Split APKs by Target Arechetecture make this Checkable in unity inside

other Options